# How to protect an eBPF firewall in traffic filter (tc-bpf)

Tags: c, linux, firewall, traffic, bpf

I'm going to implement a firewall on the traffic control classifier(man 8 tc-bpf). The firewall is to filter outgoing traffic.
But, there is one point which makes the task really hard. My userspace agent must know, is that filter(classifier) loaded and passing all outgoing traffic through itself or not.
Please tell me:

1. How to protect loaded filter from unloading(tc filter [ replace |
   delete]) or other measures which could make it aside of all traffic?
2. How to hook up on traffic control filters changing to let
   userspace agent to take appropriate measures.
3. Other ways to implement such kind of the firewall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. One needs privileges to set (or remove) TC classifiers, so unprivileged users should not be able to remove your filter. I don't remember the exact set of capabilities required, on recent kernels this is probably `CAP_BPF` and `CAP_NET_ADMIN`, older kernels might require `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` (root).
2. I think there should be a Netlink notification when the classifiers are changed, you could probably hook into that.
3. The question is very broad. Are you asking how to set up a firewall on Linux? There are several frameworks available. If you want to do it with eBPF, the XDP hook (at the driver level) is something to consider, it will have a better performance than hooking on TC.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
In general case I'm trying to make a firewall with protection from ill-intentioned root user too. I.e. if a root user unload or try to get around my network filters, an user agent application must be notified to drop access to the agent's service.
And at 3rd point I asked about other ways to implement it. Even if that is non-BPF approach.

Comment: Root can do pretty much everything they want on the machine, including loading modules and change the behaviour of the kernel itself, so I'm not sure you can prevent them from doing anything, at the end of the day. Your best pick indeed would be to get a warning triggered on changes (although if they know about it, root can likely disable that). Firewalling on LInux is vast, see iptables or nftables for examples. But there's nothing that root can't undo, as far as I know. You could maybe look at access control models like SELinux or the like to restrict permissions.

Comment: I agree with you! Root can do everything. But anyway, I want to protect from it as far as it possible. 
I've checked iptables already. And it doesn't suitable to my purposes.  The root could simple avoid my checkings by the -j ACCEPT before my NFQ action. SELinux isn't presented on any linux by default, and it uses iptables to filter traffic.
Thank you for your support!